# How to get a page url by a page id?

Tags: permalinks, pages, links, wp-link-pages

I tried to use get_page_link('page-id') and get_permalink('page-id') but the error below occurred.

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function get_page_permastruct() on null in ...

How can I get a page url knowing only its ID?

Comment: Are you writing it like that with 'page-id'? You need to pass an actual id to it and it should work. ``get_permalink(4);`` or a variable with the id ``get_permalink($id);``

Comment: yes, I know. I wrote 'page-id' as an example. The problem is that it doesn't work with an existing page id. I tried it also in a fresh installation of WP.

Comment: Good, you can never be sure so I thought I'd atleast ask! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably getting that error because WordPress doesn't have the $wp_rewrite global loaded yet for some reason.  Either something deactivated it, or you're trying to run those functions before WordPress has a chance to load it.

If you're trying to do this in a plugin or in your theme's functions.php file, make sure you're inside a function that is hooked to after_setup_theme or [a hook that runs sometime after](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request). For example:

```
function get_url_of_page_id_165() {
    return get_permalink( 165 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'get_url_of_page_id_165' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$booking_url = get_permalink('15551');
echo $booking_url;
?>
```

Comment: OP said they already tried get_page_link and get_permalink and it didn't work. So I think the question is really explaining the error message, not which API to call.

Comment: I used this. THis is working fine, No need to make any function.